# How .NET 2.0 application can execute tasks from local system account using service?

Tags: c#, .net, service

I have my own dotNET service running in the system and GUI application that needs to perform some actions as local system account. For example running cmd scripts, that is written in the GUI form, the cmd.exe process is started then with redirected stdin/stdout. Application should be able to run as regular user (without admin rights). Both service and application should be written in dotNET framework version 2.0.

Is it possible to pass current WindowsIdentity from service to the application, so a thread that starts cmd or execute some other tasks could impersonate local system account? Otherwise what is the best way to pass commands from application to service in dotNET 2.0 and can this be done without using global named objects?

Comment: WTF? .net 2.0? I honestly don't even know what it can do anymore. Are you sure you can't use 3.5? That sort of requirement is like requiring IE6 support. We are on to 4.5.1 now for pete's sake!

Comment: @Aron I'm sure that I need dotNET 2.0 support.